# Why is torque not working with large polygons?

Tags: carto

It seems that torque isn't working with a "big" polygon. By "big" I mean the size of a french department.
Could you confirm that?
I would like to show the evolution of jobless rate during the last 30 years.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se.  In order to improve your chances of getting a useful answer, I would suggest that you add as much detail as you can to your question.  For this question, it would be helpful to include information such as a workflow that you tried, the data you used, and possibly any error messages you received.

Answer (score 4):

The torque library doesn't currently support polygons. We had an older experimental version of the library that had limited support of polygons, but for production we have limited it to points for now. If you want to show polygons overtime, you can recast them as points,

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(the_geom) the_geom, some_date_column FROM table_name
```

And then click options => Table from query to store this as a point table. To run the query on the fly and have a torque visualization, you also need to include the point version of the_geom_webmercator, so,

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(the_geom) the_geom, ST_Centroid(the_geom_webmercator) the_geom_webmercator, some_date_column FROM table_name
```

And then the Torque option should appear in the visualization wizard. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback, I'm going to try !