# Polygon Torque Map- problem changing polygons to points

Tags: polygon, carto, centroids, torque

I'm trying to alter my data on `cartodb map` to get maritime emissions over about 20 years- by country. Hence trying get a torque map for polygons, and  by changing polygons to points based on a [previous suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81049/why-is-torque-not-working-with-large-polygons):

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(the_geom) the_geom, carto_date FROM maritime_emissions_my_data_trial_copy
```

But I keep getting a `syntax error at SELECT...`. `the_geom` appears to be properly valued - all rows state "Polygon".

My data is here: http://bit.ly/1M77NjG

I'm quite a novice.

Comment: Did you update the_geom_webmercator as stated in the post you refer to. You are probably better off creating a new table with points instead of polygons and running torque off that. As far as I know, polygons are still not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there! The difference is that CartoDB needs the geometry to be aliased as `the_geom_webmercator`. Also, make sure to use the (hidden) `the_geom_webmercator` to avoid having to project `the_geom` to web mercator. You should also include the primary key of the table (`cartodb_id`).

The following should work:

```
SELECT 
    ST_Centroid(the_geom_webmercator) As the_geom_webmercator, 
    carto_date,
    cartodb_id
FROM 
  maritime_emissions_my_data_trial_copy
```

Comment: Thankyou for suggestion - tried that but still getting "syntax error in or around SELECT"!

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure that there is no other text in the SQL tray other than the query in the code block above? I got the query working from the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I would assume that there is an error in the `SELECT` statement which is independent of the data. Is the missing comma between `ST_Centroid(the_geom)` and `the_geom` a typo in the post?

Does

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(the_geom), the_geom, carto_date FROM maritime_emissions_my_data_trial_copy
```

instead of

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(the_geom) the_geom, carto_date FROM maritime_emissions_my_data_trial_copy
```

?

If not, please post the full error message.

Comment: Thankyou for suggestion - tried that but still getting "syntax error in or around SELECT"!

Comment: Which error message do you exactly get?

Comment: "syntax error in or around SELECT"